# Intellij idea CE command line start for mac osx

Tags: intellij-idea

Just switched to intellij idea CE 2016.2. I'd like to know how to setup command line start for "idea". I created a link in the usr/local/bin, but got this error

idea[1627:20323] allVms required (null)
idea[1627:20323] Info.plist is corrupted, Absent JVMOptions key.

Comment: This also may help: https://gist.github.com/chrisdarroch/7018927

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Tools | Create Command-line Launcher... action.

Comment: Easy! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For community edition of IntelliJ - on Max OSX - here's the mac'y way :) :

- `open -a "IntelliJ IDEA CE"`